# ember cli app not working in ie9 on localhost

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-9, ember-cli

I am developing an Ember CLI App. When I deploy my app it works in Chrome and IE9. But when I use "ember serve" for development and testing on localhost it is working in Chrome but nothing happens in IE9.

I don't even get any error messages. In console there's just an empty error. Under network, all is loading fine - except it is not making any requests to my REST adapter (which is likely because the app isn't even loading.)

Has anyone experienced this behaviour? Unfortunately right now I am not able to give more information on the error since I don't have any.

Versions:
ember: 1.13.5
ember data: 1.13.7
jquery: 1.11.3

Comment: What is your `location` set to? Are you using the history api?

Comment: @Kitler I tried all settings: 'auto' app not loading in dev and prod, 'hash' app only loading and working in prod, 'history' not working in dev and prod. prod means the deployed app, dev means development on localhost.